# A few javascript issues: strange time dependence and images not loading 1st time

Tags: javascript, image, loading

I'm trying to create a script for creating an overlay containing an image and some text, but i've run into some problems

1st: the image in the overlay doesn't appear when first clicked, but does on subsequent openings.

2nd: the scrollTo function only works if put in a timeout, otherwise it appears to do nothing.

If anyone could shed any light on this, or any other mistakes i've made, it would be much appreciated.

javascript:

```
var scrollY;
var i_w;
var i_h;

function showOverlay(filepath,num){
    scrollY = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    hideOverlay();
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML ="image #: " + num + " click image to         close";
    var preload = new Image();
    preload.src = filepath;
    i_w = preload.width;
    i_h = preload.height;
    document.getElementById("blowup").width = i_w;
    document.getElementById("blowup").height = i_h;
    document.getElementById("blowup").src = filepath;   
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "inline";
    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0,scrollY)",1);
    setOverlayBounds(); //a function to orient the overlay div.
}
```

html:

```
<div id="overlay">
        <center>
            <img id="blowup" src="#" onClick="javascript:hideOverlay()">
        <br>
        <p id="num"></p>
        <br>
        </center>
</div>
```

css:

```
#overlay
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#999;
    border:medium;
    border-color:#0F0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the load event for the image to make sure, it finished loading before you execute your code. Also, you shouldn't use strings in connection with setTimeout. It's better to pass the function directly:

```
var preload = new Image();
preload.src = filepath;
preload.onload = function() {
    i_w = preload.width;
    i_h = preload.height;
    document.getElementById("blowup").width = i_w;
    document.getElementById("blowup").height = i_h;
    document.getElementById("blowup").src = filepath;   
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "inline";
    setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,scrollY);},1);
    setOverlayBounds(); //a function to orient the overlay div.
};
```

This should at least fix your first issue.